# Increment counter inside RecordReader in Hadoop

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

I have created a custom **RecordReader** for a mapreduce job

```
class PatternRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
@Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() {
        try {
            final String value = someParsingLogic();
            final boolean hasValue = value != null;
            if (hasValue) {
               someLogic();
            }else{
              // I would like to increment a counter here
              // something like context.getCounter(Counters.INVALID_INPUT).increment(1);
            }
            return hasValue;
    }
```

I would like to increment a counter if no value is returned and be able to set it in the Task context, so that it would be accessible by the job.

Is there anyway to achieve this ?